Fancy table with colors and pictures: alignment problem and internal line width
I currently use the following code to produce a fancy table (I can use something else than NiceTabular, its just the best solution I found for now):
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.15em}
\newcommand{\darkcelltext}[1]{\color{white}\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\tablepicture}[1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm,valign=c]{#1}}
\begin{NiceTabular}[width=\linewidth]{X[m]@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}[
    margin = 0pt,
    hvlines,
    rules/color=blue!50!black,
]
\CodeBefore
    \arraycolor{blue!25!white}
    \rowcolor{blue!50!black}{1}
    \columncolor{blue!50!black}{1}
\Body
& \darkcelltext{Column A} & \darkcelltext{Column B} & \darkcelltext{Column C} \\
\darkcelltext{Picture}&\tablepicture{red_960x640.jpg}&\tablepicture{red_960x640.jpg}&\tablepicture{red_960x640.jpg}\\
\darkcelltext{Text} & test 1 & test 2 & test 3 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}

It produces the current result:



Here are the 3 problems I would like to solve:

There is currently a very tiny (and very annoying) extra space between the picture of the column C and the right external border of the table. Where does it come from and how to remove it?
How to vertically AND horizontally center the text of the first column? ("picture" and "text")
How to change the color AND width of the internal borders (but not external), for example, how to put them in dark green with a linewidth of 1pt?

I tried several things but nothing seems to work.

Just in case here is the picture file I am currently using:


Here is a solution with nicematrix (but I'm not sure that nicematrix is the best tool for such work).
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{MyBlue}{rgb}{0,0,0.75}

\newlength{\Heavy}
\setlength{\Heavy}{1mm}

\newlength{\Thin}
\setlength{\Thin}{0.5mm}


\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
      {
        letter = H ,
        command = HeavyRule ,
        total-width = 0.5 \Heavy
      } ,
    custom-line = 
      {
        letter = : ,
        command = ThinRule ,
        tikz = { line width = \Thin , color = DarkGreen } ,
        total-width = \Thin
      } ,
  }

\newcolumntype{I}{@{}:@{}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
%
%
\begin{center}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0pt}
%
\newcommand{\darkcelltext}[1]{\color{white}\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\tablepicture}[1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm,valign=c]{#1}}
%
\begin{NiceTabular}{X[m,c]@{}cIcIc@{}H}[margin = 0pt]
\CodeBefore
  \arraycolor{blue!25!white}
  \rowcolor{MyBlue}{1}
  \columncolor{MyBlue}{1}
\Body
  & \darkcelltext{Column A} 
  & \darkcelltext{Column B} 
  & \darkcelltext{Column C} \\
\darkcelltext{Picture}
  &\tablepicture{red_960x640.jpg}
  &\tablepicture{red_960x640.jpg}
  &\tablepicture{red_960x640.jpg}\\
\ThinRule
  \darkcelltext{Text} 
  & test 1 
  & test 2 
  & test 3 \\
\HeavyRule
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [color = MyBlue, line width = 1mm] (1-|last) |- (last-|1) ;
\end{NiceTabular}
%
\end{center}
%
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}


The rules do not overlap on the pictures.
If you don't want to see the green rules in the first column and the first row:
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{MyBlue}{rgb}{0,0,0.75}

\newlength{\Heavy}
\setlength{\Heavy}{1mm}

\newlength{\Thin}
\setlength{\Thin}{0.5mm}


\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
      {
        letter = H ,
        command = HeavyRule ,
        total-width = 0.5 \Heavy
      } ,
    custom-line = 
      {
        letter = : ,
        command = ThinRule ,
        tikz = { line width = \Thin , color = DarkGreen } ,
        total-width = \Thin
      } ,
  }

\newcolumntype{I}{@{}:@{}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
%
%
\begin{center}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0pt}
%
\newcommand{\darkcelltext}[1]{\color{white}\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\tablepicture}[1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm,valign=c]{#1}}
%
\begin{NiceTabular}{X[m,c]@{}cIcIc@{}H}[margin = 0pt]
\Block[fill=MyBlue]{1-*}{}
\Block[fill=MyBlue]{*-1}{}
  & \darkcelltext{Column A} 
  & \darkcelltext{Column B} 
  & \darkcelltext{Column C} \\
\darkcelltext{Picture}
  &\tablepicture{red_960x640.jpg}
  &\tablepicture{red_960x640.jpg}
  &\tablepicture{red_960x640.jpg}\\
\ThinRule
  \darkcelltext{Text} 
  & \rowcolor{blue!25!white} test 1 
  & test 2 
  & test 3 \\
\HeavyRule
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [color = MyBlue, line width = 1mm] (1-|last) |- (last-|1) ;
\end{NiceTabular}
%
\end{center}
%
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}


